# After I updated MacOS latest version Monterey, the python can't be executed?

Tags: python-3.x, macos-monterey

I updated latest MacOS version Monterey, but python can't be executed in terminal. The same situation occurred in PyCharm.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5gtR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EMiB.png)

```
dyld[25738]: dyld cache '/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h' not loaded: syscall to map cache into shared region failed
```

dyld[25738]: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5gtR.png)    25738 abort      python3

Comment: Python 3.7 does not come with macOS. You should probably uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: Just FYI you might want to include a better description for your pictures, which currently show as "enter image description here"